# Padding для карты Gmaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Нужно получить `bounds` карты не учитывая по ,например, 15px с каждой стороны.(как бы `padding` у карты);

Суть проблемы, bound-ы в виде координат lat,lng - не получится осуществить изменением координат таким путем: lat-0.004, lng -0.00x, так как при разном zoom нужно отнимать разные значения.

Сейчас пытаюсь превратить координаты из lat,lng в пиксельные координаты, от них отнять по 15 пикселей и снова переконвертировать в lat,lng.
Но пока не получается, может есть идеи?

**ОТВЕТ:**

```
var scale = Math.pow(2,myMap.getZoom());
var gbounds = myMap.getBounds();
var proj = myMap.getProjection();
var topRight = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(gbounds.getNorthEast());
var bottomLeft = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(gbounds.getSouthWest());
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var sw = new google.maps.Point(((topRight.x * scale) - 30)/ scale, ((topRight.y * scale) + 80)/ scale);
bounds.extend(proj.fromPointToLatLng(sw));
var ne = new google.maps.Point(((bottomLeft.x * scale) + 20)/ scale, ((bottomLeft.y * scale) - 10)/ scale);
bounds.extend(proj.fromPointToLatLng(ne));
var opts = {
    bounds: bounds,
    map: myMap,
    editable:true
};
var rect = new google.maps.Rectangle(opts);
```

На выходе получаем переменную bounds с готовыми пиксельными отступами, прямоугольник рисовал для: наглядности, тестирования, внесения изменений.

Comment: сформулируйте, пожалуйста, сам **вопрос**. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Добавил более детальное описание